# Enity Framework With MySQL

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I am getting the following error

"The Entity Framework provider type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information."

However I do have MySql.Data.dll and MySql.Data.Entity.dll and also MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll referenced in my project (comes from MySQL Connector Net 6.8.3)

Here is my App.conf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
  <configSections>
   <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
   <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
 </configSections>
 <connectionStrings>
  <add name="inspectm_inspectContext" connectionString="server=--user id=--;password=--;database=--;persistsecurityinfo=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider"
    invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
    description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
    type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="inspectm_inspectContext" connectionString="server=--;user id=--;password=--;database=--;persistsecurityinfo=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
     <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
     </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

My Complete App.conf this worked for me

First I removed

```
<DbProviderFactories>
<add name="MySQL Data Provider"
invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

Then I changed

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data" />
```

And Added the provider

```
<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
```

Comment: Can you add some notes on what the change was?

Answer (score 5):

for anyone facing the same problem, here is the line that causes the Exception is this

```
<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity" />
```

Just append .EF6 to MySql.Data.Entity such that the provider is like this

```
<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
```

As such your choice to remove the code within  didn't help solve the problem. I hope this helps someone.

Comment: With Connector .NET 8.0 the referenced file is now `MySql.Data.EntityFramework.dll` so instead of `MySql.Data.Entity.EF6` you may have to use `MySql.Data.EntityFramework` in its place. The new file is still considered to be Framework 6.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this:

```cs
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class DemoContext : DbContext{}
{
```

Comment: what is "DbConfigurationType"? It's not coming up as a suggested import in VS.

Comment: @StealthRabbi it is on the `MySql.Data.EntityFramework` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Check for an inner exception.

I get

`{"Inheritance security rules violated by type:
 'MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration'. Derived types must either
 match the security accessibility of the base type or be less
 accessible.":"MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration"}`

That points me to:
[Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47227495/inheritance-security-rules-violated-by-type-mysql-data-entity-mysqlefconfigura)

I dont really like to downgrade. But so far i haven't found a better answer.