# Error 175: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' is either not registered in the machine or application config file

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, edmx

One of my clients gave me a VS2015 solution file which I am supposed to work on. However, I am unable to compile it. I am using VS2015 as well.

It uses Entity Framework, which I do not know much about.

The error given is : Error 175: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.

The error points to an an EDMX File which is as follows:

I do not know where to start or how to resolve this. Any help? Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="3.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
  <!-- EF Runtime content -->
  <edmx:Runtime>
    <!-- SSDL content -->
    <edmx:StorageModels>
      <Schema Namespace="NFMTestModel.Store" Provider="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="5.7" Alias="Self" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns:customannotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2013/11/edm/customannotation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl">
        <!--Errors Found During Generation:
warning 6002: The table/view 'def.nfm.air' does not have a primary key defined. The key has been inferred and the definition was created as a read-only table/view.-->
        <EntityType Name="air">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="DateAndTime" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="DateAndTime" Type="datetime" Precision="0" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Air_System_Air_line_1_Service_Pressure_Value" Type="double" />
          <Property Name="Air_System_Air_line_2_emergency_Pressure_Value" Type="double" />
          <Property Name="Air_System_Air_Manlock_point_11_Pressure_Value" Type="double" />
          <Property Name="Air_System_Air_Manlock_point_12_Pressure_Value" Type="double" />
          <Property Name="Air_System_Air_Manlock_point_21_Pressure_Value" Type="double" />
          <Property Name="Air_System_Air_Manlock_point_22_Pressure_Value" Type="double" />
          <Property Name="Air_System_Air_Manlock_regulation_Pressure_Value" Type="double" />
          <Property Name="Air_System_Air_System_Pressure_Value" Type="double" />
        </EntityType>
        <!--Errors Found During Generation:
warning 6002: The table/view 'def.nfm.articulation' does not have a primary key defined. The key has been inferred and the definition was created as a read-only table/view.-->
        <EntityType Name="articulation">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="DateAndTime" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="DateAndTime" Type="datetime" Precision="0" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Articulation_Angle_Horizontal_Value" Type="double" />
          <Property Name="Articulation_Angle_Vertical_Value" Type="double" />
          <Property Name="Articulation_Force_Value" Type="double" />
          <Property Name="Articulation_Pushing_in_X_Value" Type="double" />
          <Property Name="Articulation_Pushing_in_Y_Value" Type="double" />
          <Property Name="Articulation_Speed_Value" Type="double" />
          <Property Name="Articulation_Bottom_Side_Delta_Pressure_Value" Type="double" />
          <Property Name="Articulation_Bottom_Side_Elongation_LH_Value" Type="double" />
          <Property Name="Articulation_Bottom_Side_Elongation_RH_Value" Type="double" />
          <Property Name="Articulation_Bottom_Side_Elongation_Setpoint_Value" Type="double" />
          <Property Name="Articulation_Bottom_Side_Elongation_Start_point_Value" Type="double" />
          <Property Name="Articulation_Bottom_Side_Elongation_Virtual_Value" Type="double" />
          <Property Name="Articulation_Bottom_Side_Extend_Pressure_Value" Type="double" />
          <Property Name="Articulation_Bottom_Side_Force_Value" Type="double" />
          <Property Name="Articulation_Bottom_Side_High_Limit_Value" Type="double" />
          <Property Name="Articulation_Bottom_Side_Low_Limit_Value" Type="double" />
          <Property Name="Articulation_Bottom_Side_Retract_Pressure_Value" Type="double" />
```

Comment: will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21954207/enity-framework-with-mysql#

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the MySql.Data package. Try to reinstall the package from Nuget Package manager. Not sure but this may ve solve your problem.