# Entity Framework error with MySql Connection string

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I'm doing an application in cmd with entity framework to study, I'm using MySql database with the database already created and connected to visual studio, but I can not open the application, which is simple for now, below the application codes And the error:

**RdiContext.cs**

```
using rdi_musica.core;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace rdi_musica.infra
{
   public class RdiContext : DbContext
   {
       public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Genero> Generos { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Banda> Bandas { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Musica> Musicas { get; set; }

   }
}
```

**BandaRepository.cs**

```
using rdi_musica.core;
using System.Linq;

namespace rdi_musica.infra
{
    public class BandaRepository
    {
       RdiContext context = new RdiContext();
       public Banda getBandaById(int Id)
       {
           var b = context.Bandas.Where(x => x.Id == Id).Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
           return b;
       }
    }
 }
```

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Default" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;database=redeinova_musica;uid=root;password=root"/>
</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
   <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
   <!--defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" /-->
   <providers>
     <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"/>
     <!--provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" /-->
    <!--provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider-->
  </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
   <DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
 </system.data>
</configuration>
```

And the error:

[image]

Error transcription:

```
The Entity Framework provider type 
'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6' 
 registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with 
 invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' could not be loaded.
```

The project structure:

[image]

Ps: Yes, I installed the MySql drivers and added the references

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From first glance seems that you must set `DbConfigurationTypeAttribute` on `DbContext` class to use MySQL:

```
namespace rdi_musica.infra
{
   [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
   public class RdiContext : DbContext
   {
       public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Genero> Generos { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Banda> Bandas { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Musica> Musicas { get; set; }

   }
}
```

NB: In EF 5 with MySQL connector version below 6.8.x your data context setup seems working fine, but in EF 6 with MySQL connector version 6.8.x and above you need to explicitly set `DbConfigurationType` to use `MySql.Data.Entity` namespace.

If it's still not enough (i.e. throwing same exception), try adding `codeConfigurationType` into web.config:

```
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguratio‌​n, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
...
</entityFramework>
```

Then remove part of `DbProviderFactories` inside `system.data` element:

```
<!-- taken from /a/21954322 by Donald Jansen -->
<DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

And modify provider setting inside `entityFramework` element to this:

```
<!-- taken from /a/21954322 by Donald Jansen -->
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguratio‌​n, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
    ...
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Reference:

[Entity Framework Config File Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj556606(v=vs.113).aspx)

[Entity Framework Code-Based Configuration (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj680699(v=vs.113).aspx)

Similar issues:

[No Entity Framework provider found for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' ADO.NET provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142841/no-entity-framework-provider-found-for-mysql-data-mysqlclient-ado-net-provider)

[Enity Framework With MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21954207/enity-framework-with-mysql)