# Visual Studio 2017 + entity framework + identity + mysql not working

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have been trying to create a REST API with visual studio 2017 using the default project.
This works fine with a SQL local DB, but when I am trying to convert it to a MySQL variant using this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider

I get this error:

```
'The Entity Framework provider type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.'
```

This tutorial worked fine with visual studio 2015.
I noticed that other stuff like dotnet connector from either devart or mysql do not work for visual studio 2017 yet, am I to early?

I have tried these solutions:
 - [Enity Framework With MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21954207/enity-framework-with-mysql)

EDIT: Forgot to tell what I tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That tutorial is from 2013. MySQL connector doesn't yet support visual studio 2017, It's expected shortly, in the meantime Devart has a connector that works with Visual Studio 2017 and MySQL.

**Edit**

MySQL now natively supports Visual Studio 2017. More info at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-install.html

Comment: I draw the same conclusion Altho entity framework still doesn't work flawless not for SQL nor for mysql it crashes on creating a ado.net model. But I have solved the problem by following the tutorial again with the SO link and added 1 line of code to the entity framework :)

Answer (score 2):

Might be helpful for others. MySQL Supports Visual Studio 2017 in version 1.2.7 Click on the below link for more details

https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,656703,656703#msg-656703