# Unable to create working database connection / datasource

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2017

I'm writing to create a standard *.NET 4.6 Windows Form* application (with *Visual Studio 2017*). The database backend is *MySQL Server Community* 5.7.21.
I also installed *MySQL for Visual Studio* 1.2.7 and *Connector/NET* 6.10.5.
In my application I would like to use *EntityFramework 6* (with a database first approach).
I add to my application the following nuget packages:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="MySql.Data" version="6.10.6" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="MySql.Data.Entity" version="6.10.6" targetFramework="net46" />
</packages>
```

I stumbled into a number of issues:

1. I cannot add an ADO .NET Entity Data Model to my application because the only providers available for the connection are those depicted below:

[image]

2. I cannot create a datasource for the same issue as previous point.
3. Even if I'm able to create a data connection to MySQL schemas I cannot edit tables trough Visual Studio ... I got this error when trying:

[image]

I already tried to uninstall/re-install MySQL components and/or create several application with different frameworks (4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2) but I always got the same error.

Is there a way to make Visual Studio 2017 work with MySQL and EF6?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

Comment: @LaviniaN. you managed to fix the issue I got following this tutorial?

Comment: No, but take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217634/visual-studio-2017-entity-framework-identity-mysql-not-working. It might not yet be supported in VS2017.