# Getting Entity Framework to generate SQL with the backtick identifiers expected by MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to get code first Entity Framework to work with an existing MySQL database. I got Entity Framework v6.2.0 and MySQL.Data.Entity v6.9.11 from NuGet. I did try MySQL.Data.Entity v6.10.7, but reverted to 6.9.11 after being blocked by the same [Inheritance security rules problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47227495/inheritance-security-rules-violated-by-type-mysql-data-entity-mysqlefconfigura) as this question.

The config contains the following (username and password removed for obvious reasons):

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySql" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="SERVER=sql-dev;Database=pen;UID=****;PWD=****;Allow User Variables=True;" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

By reverting to v6.9.11 I have got to the point where I can query the DbSet and see the SQL that it is generating in the debugger. I can connect, and it recognises that the schema is correct but when I try to perform a simple test query it fails.

```
 Assert.IsTrue(context.BinLocs.Count() > 0);
```

Using the debugger I have found out that it fails because the query it generates SQL uses a syntax optimised for SQL Server, which does not work for MySQL.

The SQL that Entity Framework generated was:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[TID] AS [TID], 
    [Extent1].[zone] AS [zone], 
    [Extent1].[ProdCode] AS [ProdCode], 
    [Extent1].[chute] AS [chute]
FROM [dbo].[tbl_s_products_binlocs] AS [Extent1];
```

Unfortunately the database has been set to use ` as quote identifiers and there is no dbo schema. Knowing this I can easily get this SQL to work by manually changing the SQL to take this into account:

```
SELECT 
    `Extent1`.`TID` AS `TID`, 
    `Extent1`.`zone` AS `zone`, 
    `Extent1`.`ProdCode` AS `ProdCode`, 
    `Extent1`.`chute` AS `chute`
FROM `tbl_s_products_binlocs` AS `Extent1`;
```

When I run this SQL against the database I get the results that I expected. I cannot change the way database expects identifiers to be quoted because there are already legacy programs that have to be kept running and assume this syntax. So I need to get Entity Framework to generate SQL that will work with the existing database.

How do I get Entity Framework to generate SQL with the backtick quoted identifiers expected by MySQL?

---

Updated to include the configuration settings

Comment: `it fails.` What exception does it throw?

Comment: I wonder why the provider is not generating a `SELECT COUNT(*)...` query.

Comment: @TsahiAsher I think because in EF you can map one or all colums in a table and it the provider cannot know if what you selected to be mapped is every column or just a few. Launching select * will select every column in the table on the database no matter what you need or what you configured to be mapped by the ORM

Comment: The MySQL provider indeed uses (hardcoded) ``` for quoted identifiers (and no `dbo`), and the generated SQL queries look like the desired example. Something is wrong at your side (configuration or something).

Comment: @LiquidCore I think Tsahi Asher question is reasonable, because `context.BinLocs.Count()` should generate different (`COUNT`) based SQL than the posted by OP.

Comment: @IvanStoev I don't get what you are saying. I just explained to Tsahi why the framework does not generate a select * statement. There was no criticism at all intended

Comment: @LiquidCore I'm saying (like Tsahi) that `context.BinLocs.Count()` should generate `SELECT COUNT(*)`

Comment: @IvanStoev `SELECT COUNT(*)`, not `SELECT (*)`.

Comment: I agree with @IvanStoev. Check that your connection string is configured with the MySql provider (`provider` attribute in the value of the `connectionString` attribute).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the Framework generator.

Follow [this](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework.Extended/issues/178).